# Circular slide annimation two views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In my Android application project I'm trying to  show two views (ImageView and TextView) with using animation project. In result I want to have sliding elements from left to right with pause time without any move in the center. In addition I want to introduce alpha animation.

At this moment I've started with experiments to only one element and I've defined animation in this way:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="true">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-15%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart"/>

    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="15%p"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart"/>
</set>
```

Unfortunately effect which I get is completely vary what I expect.

Do you have any advices how can I achieve animation effect like this:

- 1 sec. slide in (alpha from 0.0 to 1.0)
- 2 sec. wait without move (alpha stay 1.0)
- 1 sec. slide out (alpha from 1.0 to 0.0)

Comment: use two animations: slidein/fadein and slideout/fadeout

Comment: So if I split my animation to two separated (in and out) then I should add extra timer to measure 2 sec. pause, or should I use startOffset in slideout? How and when should I start slideout animation? It will be good place to begin this animation in onAnimationEnd (AnimationListener) attached to slidein?

Comment: yes, use animation listener and the Handler to post a Runnable after 2 sec, or just Handler with 3 sec delay